# How can I navigation up and down a ul using two buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple ul and need to be able to navigate up and down the different li, using a up and down button. That way when the up button is clicked and will select each li, until it gets to the top of the ul and then you can press the down button to navigate back down, selecting the next li, each time the button is clicked.

Not sure how to go about this...

```
    <div id="MainMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">PATIENT TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">QC TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">REVIEW RESULTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">OTHER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm using the following jQuery code to switch the class for the active li...

```
 $("li:not(.active)").live("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("menuActive");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("menuActive");
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're selecting the right class name? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Us4q9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this:

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Us4q9/3/

```
<div id="MainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">PATIENT TEST</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">QC TEST</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REVIEW RESULTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OTHER</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" id="btnUp">Up</a>
<a href="#" id="btnDown">Down</a>


 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnDown').click(function () {
            var $current = $('#MainMenu ul li.active');
            if ($current.next().length > 0) {
                $('#MainMenu ul li').removeClass('active');
                $current.next().addClass('active');
            }
        });

        $('#btnUp').click(function () {
            var $current = $('#MainMenu ul li.active');
            if ($current.prev().length > 0) {
                $('#MainMenu ul li').removeClass('active');
                $current.prev().addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
```

Or using keyboard navigation:

```
  $(window).keyup(function (e) {
            var $current = $('#MainMenu ul li.active');
            var $next;
            if (e.keyCode == 38)
                $next = $current.prev();
            if (e.keyCode == 40)
                $next = $current.next();

            if ($next.length > 0) {
                $('#MainMenu ul li').removeClass('active');
                $next.addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Note also you're only handling a mouse click, not the key press functionality that the OP is asking about.

Comment: added navigation through the keyboard

Comment: Thanks...That worked like a charm :) How can I call a function, when a li is active, and the user clicks a button, but only when that li is active?

Comment: I have an OK  button and I need to wire up a function, so that when the OK button is clicked it can check for the active li and call a function based on which li is active.

Comment: oh, just take a `$('#MainMenu ul li.active a').text()` if you just want inner text of the link inside of it

Answer (score 2):

Use a keydown listener and use keycodes 38 and 40 for up and down arrows.

```
$(document).keydown( function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( keyCode === 38 ) {
        // up arrow pressed
    } else if ( keyCode === 40 ) {
        // down arrow pressed
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (You will need to click the body first for it to work).

```
var selid=0;
var numlis =$("#MainMenu > ul > li").length;
$(licn(0)).addClass("menuActive");
$("li:not(.active)").live("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("menuActive");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("menuActive");
});

$("body").live("keydown",function(e) {
    if(e.which==38)
    {
        changeSel(-1);
    }
    else if(e.which==40)
    {
        changeSel(1);
    }
});
function licn(n)
{
    return "#MainMenu > ul > li:nth-child("+(n+1)+")";
}
function changeSel(dir)
{
    $(licn(selid)).removeClass("menuActive");
    selid+=dir;
    selid%=numlis;
    if(selid<0)
    {
        selid+=numlis;
    }
    $(licn(selid)).addClass("menuActive");
}
```