# how to select a li a based on the text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select a given li a element so that it is selected by default?

Please refer to this question to see the example that I'm working with...

[How can I navigation up and down a ul using two buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295346/how-can-i-navigation-up-and-down-a-ul-using-two-buttons)

Basically I need to select the Patient Test li a item by default.

Comment: Your title and question do not match.

Comment: Basically I'm setting an active class to a li a element, when the user clicks an Up and Down button, then based on the li a item that has the active class, I call a function. I need to make sure the active class is always applied to a cretin li element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to create an ID for each li and then use jQuery addClass and removeClass to swap the classes.

```
  $("#repeatMenuItem").removeClass("active");
  $("#deleteMenuItem").removeClass("active");
  $("#okMenuItem").addClass("active");
```

Comment: This workes..so please don't down vote it, just because you provided an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
 $("#MainMenu li:contains('PATIENT TEST')").click();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
$('li a').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == 'PATIENT TEST'){
    //do something here
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/uuaKH/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#MainMenu li > a').eq(0).focus()
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

set in the loaded html, since the next click will remove and reset the "status", based on the other post

```
<div id="MainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menuActive"><a href="#">PATIENT TEST</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">QC TEST</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REVIEW RESULTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OTHER</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did this already in the code and it works only the first time the application is ran. After that it keeps the last item selected highlighted, when I need to to always default to the PATIENT TEST.

Comment: this makes no sense, html doesn't change it self...i dont think im understanding what you are saying, maybe you can add a secondary class like menuDefault and apply the same css rule to that class, so then only the "menuActive" will be added/removed; or add a custom identifier (id) to the html element and manipulate him with jquery..

Comment: also you can default the value inside your function so if the value doesn't change (i mean, you dont 'set' it) by user clicks on the up/down, the 'patient test' is used